# How do I use an if statement inside of setText?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, settext

I want to have a `setText` with an `if` statement inside, so I can easily pick a value for viewing. I remember seeing something like it in MIT App Inventor, so I think it's possible.

For example,

```
textView.setText(if (value == 0) {"no"}else {"yes"};
```

Comment: `textView.setText((value == 0) ? "no" : "yes");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator).

```java
textView.setText(value == 0 ? "no" : "yes");
```

Note that you can always just write out the `if` and `else` statements directly, though.

```java
if (value == 0) textView.setText("no");
else textView.setText("yes");
```